# Segmentation fault (core dumped) C programming pthreads Histogram

Tags: c, pthreads, histogram

I was doing Histogram using pthreads and after long struggle on it.. finally it says 'Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)'. unfortunately I had this line p=(struct1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct1)); after getting the values to the struct variables from command line.. So that was cleared off.. Thanks for @DNT for letting me know that..

Now when I try to execute the following program.. It sometimes displays the output and sometimes it is going out to the which_bin function and prints the following

output type 1(which is not the correct output):
Data = 0.000000 doesn't belong to a bin!
Quitting

output type 2(almost the correct output of histo with time taken by threads):
10.000-28.000:
28.000-46.000:
46.000-64.000:
64.000-82.000:
82.000-100.000: XXXXXXXXXX
The code to be timed took 0.000415 seconds

My ques is why the same prog when ran shows different outputs.. I am confused of what it is exactly looking for..

Here is my code..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "timer.h"
void Usage(char prog_name[]);



//void Get_args(void *p);
void Gen_data(void *p);
void Gen_bins(void *p);
int Which_bin(void *p);
void Print_histo(void *p);


void func(void *p);

struct test
{
    int bin_count, i, bin;
    float min_meas, max_meas;
    float* bin_maxes;
    int* bin_counts;
    int data_count;
    float* data;
};

typedef struct test struct1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double start, finish, elapsed;
    GET_TIME(start);

    struct1 *p;
    pthread_t th1, th2, th3;

    p=(struct1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct1));
    if (argc != 5)
        Usage(argv[0]);
    p->bin_count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    p->min_meas = strtof(argv[2], NULL);
    p->max_meas = strtof(argv[3], NULL);
    p->data_count = strtol(argv[4], NULL, 10);

    p->bin_maxes = malloc(p->bin_count*sizeof(float));
    p->bin_counts = malloc(p->bin_count*sizeof(int));
    p->data = malloc(p->data_count*sizeof(float));


    pthread_create(&th1,NULL,(void*) Gen_data,(void*) p);
    pthread_create(&th2,NULL,(void*) Gen_bins,(void*) p);
    pthread_create(&th3,NULL,(void*) func,(void*) p);
    printf("Hi\n");


    pthread_join(th1,NULL);
    pthread_join(th2,NULL);
    pthread_join(th3,NULL);


    Print_histo(p);
    free(p->data);
    free(p->bin_maxes);
    free(p->bin_counts);

    GET_TIME(finish);
    elapsed = finish - start;
    printf("The code to be timed took %f seconds\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
}  /* main */

void func(void *p)
{
    int i;
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;

    for (i = 0; i < args->data_count; i++)
    {
        args->bin = Which_bin(args);
        args->bin_counts[args->bin]++;
    }

    #  ifdef DEBUG
        printf("bin_counts = ");
        for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
            printf("%d ", args->bin_counts[i]);
        printf("\n");
    #  endif
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function:  Usage
 * Purpose:   Print a message showing how to run program and quit
 * In arg:    prog_name:  the name of the program from the command line
 */
void Usage(char prog_name[] /* in */)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s ", prog_name);
    fprintf(stderr, "<bin_count> <min_meas> <max_meas> <data_count>\n");
    exit(0);
}  /* Usage */


void Gen_data(void *p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    int i;
    srandom(0);
    for (i = 0; i < args->data_count; i++)
        args->data[i] = args->min_meas + (args->max_meas - args->min_meas)*random()/((double) RAND_MAX);

    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("data = ");
        for (i = 0; i < args->data_count; i++)
            printf("%4.3f ", args->data[i]);
        printf("\n");
    #endif
} /* Gen_data */


void Gen_bins(void* p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    float bin_width;
    int   i;
    bin_width = (args->max_meas - args->min_meas)/args->bin_count;

    for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
    {
        args->bin_maxes[i] = args->min_meas + (i+1)*bin_width;
        args->bin_counts[i] = 0;
    }

    #  ifdef DEBUG
        printf("bin_maxes = ");
        for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
            printf("%4.3f ", args->bin_maxes[i]);
        printf("\n");
    #  endif
}

int Which_bin(void* p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    int bottom = 0, top =  args->bin_count-1;
    int mid;
    float bin_max, bin_min;

    while (bottom <= top)
    {
        mid = (bottom + top)/2;
        bin_max = args->bin_maxes[mid];
        bin_min = (mid == 0) ? args->min_meas: args->bin_maxes[mid-1];
        if (*(args->data) >= bin_max)
            bottom = mid+1;
        else if (*(args->data) < bin_min)
            top = mid-1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Data = %f doesn't belong to a bin!\n", args->data);
    fprintf(stderr, "Quitting\n");
    exit(-1);
}

void Print_histo(void *p)
{
    struct1 *args;
    args=(struct1*)p;
    int i, j;
    float bin_max, bin_min;

    for (i = 0; i < args->bin_count; i++)
    {
        bin_max = args->bin_maxes[i];
        bin_min = (i == 0) ? args->min_meas: args->bin_maxes[i-1];
        printf("%.3f-%.3f:\t", bin_min, bin_max);
        for (j = 0; j < args->bin_counts[i]; j++)
            printf("X");
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* Print_histo */
```

I would like to know if the program is logically wrong? if it is wrong logically in that case why is it showing the histogram output at times.. Thanks!

Comment: Please use a debugger to narrow down your issue.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of C before doing advanced programming such as multi-threading. If you read your program from main() and downwards, you should be able to find the bug within a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about moving this line

```
p=(struct1 *)malloc(sizeof(struct1));
```

before 'p' is used to allocate the members.

Comment: Thanks! now i do not see the segmentation fault (core dumped).. and not the correct output too :) I have to start my fight on this again :)

Comment: You may want to check the logic in your code carefully from the beginning, and make sure that it actually does what you want it to do. One way is to run each routine by itself without threads to see if it works, and at the end when you have verified correctness, put it all together again:)

Comment: Firstly i have created the serial histogram program and then when I saw the correctness of it.. then I started with pthreads.. thanks!

Comment: In that case, I suggest you synchronize your last function, so that all the data have been generated before it starts using them. Threads order of execution is undefined, so your 'func' may not find everything in its place unless you devise a way to do your calculations incrementally, and wait when data is not available yet. You may want to look into mutexes for example (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/)

Comment: Thanks you.. I will look forward to implement mutexes in this histo

Comment: Hi.. as you said to sync the last func.. do you mean that print_histo function is not having the correct data before it displays the histo in command prompt? But before print_histo function I have joined all threads and so only when the threads are done with their execution then the main program resumes the print_histo after join.. So isnt that print_histo is having all its data before it starts displaying it?

Comment: You have Gen_data in thread 1 which sets args->data, then Gen_bins that sets args->maxes and args->counts in thread 2 and then in thread 3 you set some of the same struct members and also call Which_Bin that uses the data in the struct. All these run concurrently, so Which_Bin is not guaranteed to find the data where it should be unless you sync the threads. Also, look at classic asynchronous producer-consumer problems.